# Hive SaveAsTable creates a new Parquet table file for every run

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, parquet

I have the following Scala code that I use to write data from a json file to a table in Hive. 
    import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("App").setMaster("local")

import org.apache.spark.sql.hive._

val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
val stg_comments = hiveContext.read.schema(buildSchema()).json(<path to json file)

comment.write.mode("append").saveAsTable(<table name>)
```

My json data has newline and carriage return characters in it's field values and hence, I cannot simply insert records in Hive (because Hive tables by default do not store newline and carriage returns in the data values) and hence, I need to use **SaveAsTable** option. The issue here is that every time a json file is read and new records are appended to the existing table, a new parquet file is created in the table directory in Hive warehouse directory. This leads to really small small parquet files in the directory. I would like the data to be appended to the existing parquet file. Do we know how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behavior. There is no append-to-existing file option here. Each job has its own set of tasks, each task has its own output file. `repartitioning` before rewrite can reduce number of files written, but not prevent creating new files.

If number of files becomes a problem, you have to run a separate job to read existing small files and merge into larger chunks.

Comment: Thanks! How do I merge the small files into larger chunks without having to create a new table?